# Кнопка на слайдере

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Привет всем. В общем создал слайдер, и в каждой странице слайдера есть по две кнопки. Нужно сделать так чтобы кнопки из каждого странички слайдера направляли на отдельные Activity. Например 1-ая кнопка первой странички слайдера направлял на Activity1, 2-ая кнопка первой странички слайдера направлял на Activity2, 1-ая кнопка второй странички направлял на Activity3, итд итп. Как замутить такое? Знаю что через setOnClicklistener(), но что то мозги не дотягивают как определить именно в каком слайдере юзер нажал кнопку. Гуглил, не нашел. Спасибо заранее.

Кстати, вот код адаптера Слайдера(SliderAdapter.java):

```
package kz.pushkinlibrary.guide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Yersultan on 26.01.2018.
 */

public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int[] slide_images = {
            R.drawable.icon1,
            R.drawable.icon2,
            R.drawable.icon3
    };

    public String[] slide_headings = {
            "Заголовок1",
            "Заголовок2",
            "Заголовок3"
    };

    public String[] slide_desc = {
            "Текст1",
            "Текcт2",
            "Текст3 "
    };


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slide_headings.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == (RelativeLayout) o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false);

        ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
        TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);
        TextView slideDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_desc);

        slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
        slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
        slideDescription.setText(slide_desc[position]);


        container.addView(view);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Вот код Layout страниц слайдера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/slide_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/eat_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slide_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="ЗАГОЛОВОК"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slide_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slide_heading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Текст"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTransparentWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/slide_desc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slide_desc"
        android:layout_marginEnd="62dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же, как с ресурсами в массивах для каждой страницы, делаем ресурс с именами активити, на которые надо переходить:

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    // имена активити для первой кнопки
    Class[] activitesForOneButton = {ActivityOne.class, ActivityTwo.class, ActivityThree.class};

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ..
        Button button7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent(context, activitesForOneButton[position]);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

при нажатии на `button7` на первой странице будет переход на `ActivityOne`, на второй странице - `ActivityTwo` и так далее.

Для второй кнопки делаем аналогично.